# How to unwrap an optional dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift, swift-optionals

I have a dictionary wrapped in an optional called `optTest`. After unwrapping the optional, it looks like this:

```
["fileName": "testName",
"fileSize": 10]
```

Given `optTest`, I am trying to retrieve `fileName` from this optional but having some trouble. I've tried this:

`if let optTest = optTest` but I am getting complaints from compiler. Anyone know how to do this?

Edit: This optional is part of the callback as defined here:

```
       public func someFunc(
            _ oldPath : String,
            resolver: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
            rejector reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock)
```

Comment: By hashmap you mean Dictionary right?

Comment: Also can you post code for the how `optTest` is declared (e.g. `var optTest: [String: Any]?`)

Comment: @aheze it is part of a callback. Something like this: `resolver([
                "fileName": "testName",
                "fileSize": 10
                ])`

Comment: Can you show the code for the function's callback? Like `func getStuff(resolver: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void)` or something.

Comment: @aheze ok I added it to question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Np. But what is `RCTPromiseResolveBlock`? Option-click on it

Comment: This is what I found in the comments:  `Block that bridge modules use to resolve the JS promise waiting for a result.
Nil results are supported and are converted to JS's undefined value.`

Comment: Ok. What is your code for unwrapping `optTest`?

Comment: `if let fileName = optTest?["fileName"] { print(fileName)}` assuming  optTest is optional